# Should we add a recurring "bloopers" post to the blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

I've been thinking of ways to continually add content to the blog, and the most recent idea is to have a recurring series of posts detailing DIY "bloopers".  The general idea is for users to submit "mistakes" they've made while improving their homes, and posting 5-10 of them in a monthly/bi-monthly series.

There are a few issues to resolve, before this can be done...

- Is this even a good idea?
- Will it get enough participation?
- How will users submit their stories?
- How will we choose the best submissions?
- Can we offer a gift to the folks who submit stories that are used?

EDIT:
We also need a [name for this series](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/673/33), but maybe I'll open a new meta question for that.

Answer (score 2):

I love this!

"You're Doing it Wrong"

Answer (score 1):

The chat room seems like a good way to submit stories.

Or maybe we could track them in trello.

Comment: I'd like to have a way to vote on the best stories, so it doesn't fall to a single person to pick the best.

Comment: @Tester101 Hmm, maybe meta, each submission as it's own answer...

Comment: That's what I was thinking, ask a question on meta and allow folks to add their stories as answers. Then delete the stories that have been used.