# What should we name the "bloopers" blog series?

Tags: discussion, blog

So I guess it has been decided that we'll try to get a ["bloopers" blog series](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/670/33) started, but we're still missing one thing...  A name for the series.

## The rules

- One entry per post.
- Names must be reasonably unique (we don't want the trademark or copyright lawyers showing up).
- The top voted name wins.

<sub><sup>*If we can swing it, there may be a prize involved.*</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2):

You're Doing it Wrong!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps some of the self-deprecating [suggestions that were made for name of the site](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/what-should-our-site-be-called-and-what-should-our-domain-name-be) could be used for this, e.g., HouseBroken, SinkOverflow, or NailFail.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:...

"(How Not To) Do It Yourself"

Answer (score 0):

uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuhhh ... Do it to Yourself